# Split events and function in Javascript / CoffeeScript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have been using Backbone a lot lately and love it because it keeps my code clean.

I am just building another site and I really want to use some of the backbone / coffeescript syntax. For example for a one page loader I was thinking of doing something like this:

This is a single HTML page that loads one JavaScript file

```
#query Events    
$(document).ready =>

  $(".click").click ->
    console.log "hello"
    alert()


#Functions

  alert: ->
    console.log "alert"
```

So I can split all my functions neatly below and the events at the top. So I can keep track. In the above example I am trying to get the click event to fire on alert.

In backbone I can have an events list which trigger alerts, which I find really useful. But I do not need all the views / controllers / models etc.

At the moment though this does not work. What is the best way to have an event fire another function outside of its own function?

Maybe I am doing this really wrong, but I love the simplicity of splitting this up and keeping it clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i messed up my syntax quite a bit...

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".click").click ->
    console.log "hello"
    alert()

  alert = ->
    console.log "alert"
```

Works, if anyon else is looking to do this then this has worked for me :)